# passing static fields to a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, static, final

I wrote a small HTTP server in Java and I have a  problem passing static variables (server configuration: port, root, etc.) to the thread that handles requests.  I do not want my thread to modify these variables and if it extends the server class, it will also inherit its methods which I don't want.

I don't want to use getters for reasons of performance. If I make the static members final, I will have a problem when loading their values from the config file.

here's an example

```
class HTTPServer {
static int port; 
static File root;
etc..
....
//must be public
public void launch() throws HTTPServerException {
    loadConfig();
    while (!pool.isShutdown()) {
            ....
        //using some config here
             ...
        try {
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    Worker w = new Worker(s);
    pool.execute(w);
        }catch () {...}
    }
}
private void loadConfig(){ //reading from file};
...
other methods that must be public goes here
}
```

I also don't want to have the worker as nested class. It's in another package...

What do you propose?

Comment: First code it correctly (i.e. using getters and everything), you can worry about performance later.

Comment: These should be regular, non-static final fields of `HTTPServer`, passed in as constructor parameters. Also, don't optimize prematurely -- getters cost almost nothing, unless profiled otherwise.

Comment: In my opinion, you ask us pointers on how to make a complete mess out of it.

Comment: You are dealing with a network. Compared to that the overhead of a getter is utterly insignificant, even for frequently-read fields, which the ones you mention certainly are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your config in a final [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).  Then it can be referenced by your worker and also updated in a thread-safe manner.

Something like:

```
class HTTPServer {
  public static final AtomicReference<ServerConf> config = 
    new AtomicReference(new ServerConf());
}
```

Make the new `ServerConf` class immutable:

```
class ServerConf {
  final int port;
  final File root;
  public ServerConf(int port, File root) {
    this.port = port;
    this.root = root;
  } 
}
```

Then your worker can get a reference to the current config via `HTTPServer.config.get()`.  Perhaps something like:

```
Worker w = new Worker(s, HTTPServer.config.get());
```

`loadConfig()` can set new config via something like:

```
HTTPServer.config.set(new ServerConf(8080, new File("/foo/bar"));
```

If it's not important for all your config to change at the same time, you could skip the `ServerConf` class and use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for the port setting, and `AtomicReference<File>` for the root.

Answer (score 0):

Read the static data into a static 'sharedConfig' object that also has a socket field - you can use that field for the listening socket.  When acccpet() returns with a server<> client socket, clone() the 'sharedConfig', shove in the new socket and pass that object to the server<>client worker thread.  The thread then gets a copy of the config that it can erad and even modify if it wants to without afecting any other thread or the static config.